# Create a custom module in Magento 1.9

Tags: php, magento

Im just a junior level programmer ,please help me in create a custom module in magento to insert new order information to a custom table in database,like inserting data to a custom table when a new order is placed.Please help me out

Comment: Your question is too broad. You need to try something or show your research, rather than using Stack Overflow as a free code design and writing service.

Comment: i dont have an idea from where to start to create a module in magento,real help would be appriciated

Comment: Where have you looked for documentation or  a tutorial?

Comment: i have limited time to complete this task,while referring tutorials its really time consuming please help to create this module

Comment: @SreenathK - unfortunately, we cannot write this for you / lead you to guides, it's against the rules here, and StackOverflow is not the place for that, what we are here to do is help you to fix your issues in code you have already done, so ultimately, you are going to have to do the research or hire someone to do this for you. I don't want to put you off using the services here, but this is something we just cannot do for you, I can only apologise on all of our behalfs for the lack of help you will receive with this question

Comment: hi, @SreenathK if you are new to magento first create a custom module with setup you can easy find it then using observer save order data into your custom table thanks

Comment: ok then would you help me to get the right tutorials to do this

Comment: @SreenathK - I have to refer back to my prior comment, asking for guides / tutorials or other off-site material is off topic, and as such, against the rules, there is literally nothing we can do to help in a constructive way, not unless we want to break SO rules and guidelines - I am sorry for this, but that is how it is and how we try to maintain a high quality here on SO

Comment: It would be worth you reading through the following; https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic (#4 in particular) - I am certain people would love to help, I know I would, but as you are, we are busy people, we do not have the time to do the research for you, we do not have the time to write it for you

Comment: thanks for your valuable comment

Answer (score 0):

**To create a custom module.**
https://inchoo.net/magento/programming-magento/magento-hello-world-module-extension/

To insert the order data you can use event observer.
http://www.divisionlab.com/solvingmagento/events-and-observers-a-magento-tutorial/

**sales_order_place_after** - This event will helps to get the order data after order placed.